# Bias correction models in forecasting

Tags: forecasting, bias

A forecast model (esp. Time Series model) may not be able to self-correct forecast biases primarily because the model does not take any feedback from forecast misses. Are there methods available that can be made to do so?

Comment: This paper does exactly what you want using a boosting strategy: https://robjhyndman.com/papers/rectify.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing to this paper, very helpful